# How to call function defined in a Chrome Extension content script from the page's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

content.js

```
function foo(){
  console.log('bar');
}
foo();
```

Manifest

```
"content_scripts": [{"matches": ["<all_urls>"],"js": ["content.js"]}]
```

Everything works fine and the function executes when the page is loaded but is it possible to call this function through the console by myself?

Comment: In the Developers Tools' Console, there is a drop down menu to choose the context of execution. Choose your extension's content script to call its functions there.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivàn already pointed out, you need to change the context of execution from the Developers Tools' console. In the top left corner there is a dropdown menu, from there you can change the context. I attached a screenshot to help you find it.

[image]